# How to capture all SQL sent over Ado.Net

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, ado.net, dapper

I have an application that uses both Entity Framework and Dapper. I would like to provide a custom logger to log out any sql that is issued over the ado.net connection. What is the best way of doing this?

Alternately, if it's not easily possible what exactly are the difficulties?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? Depending on timescales and how easy the upgrade path is Entity Framework 6 does support DbCommand interception: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interception

Comment: @dannykay1710 oh awesome. This project is locked into EF4 for some reason no-one's been quite able to explain to me, but I'm also off it in a week so I can use this on my next one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would [ADO.NET Data Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172144.aspx) work for you?  It plugs into ETW, from which you might be able to glue your current logging system. Doesn't seem much stand-alone though.

Answer (score 5):

Miniprofiler, which is written by the same team, works with both dapper and Entity Framework - although iirc the later requires a *bit* more work. This provides the ability for both logging and profiling of ADO.NET commands. We use it 24x7 here on stackoverflow (and the entire stack exchange network), so it works well even at scale.

Comment: How to hook that to a custom logger though? I spent some time browsing their source code and duplicating that functionality seems non-trivial

Answer (score 4):

The [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) tool offers the ability to trace SQL calls (along with a ton of other information) and is being actively promoted by the ASP.NET team: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/profile-and-debug-your-aspnet-mvc-app-with-glimpse

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the [SharpPcap API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) and listen for connections that are established between the client IP and the SQL server IP on the port that SQL runs. You can then run either regex or the like to extract out the SQL commands. Most of them will start with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT`, `DELETE` or `EXEC`. Once you have the string call whatever logger you have in place and log as needed. You can run this as a service, a second app launched by your app, or even from within the first on a second thread. It is a little bit lower down than the `ADO` pipeline but that just gives you more flexibility. You can test and compare against the traffic received by SQL profiler / SQL trace on the server to validate that it works.

The other alternative is to try and modify the relevant section of ADO.Net code and insert logging. Tools like AfterThought https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought might be an option, although I think this is asking for trouble in all but the most controlled environments especially with white listing, AV, updates, version control etc.

Comment: Just to be clear you're saying there's nothing built into Ado.Net allows this?

Comment: I think this (.ToTraceString method)is the closest you may get http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx (note only subset of queries) but no, I do not believe that there is a perfect fit for what you want. SqlCommand has next to no events you could hook nor does any of ADO.Net support injection of a logger. EFTracingProvider at bottom of articles looks promising but I can't vouch for it nor do I have enough info to say it is a good fit as you sound like you want something you can just turn on(?).

Comment: This may also be helpful, uses log4net which is a bonus. http://fknet.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/entity-framework-logging/ but again this is entity framework and the question is all traffic via ADO.Net, if all traffic outside your app and/or EF then see previous answers.

Answer (score -4):

You could use log4net: http://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/
I've been using it in a couple of big projects. Very useful as you can specify what/where you want to log.
Since you want to log SQL statements, you can put a log in you data access layer.

Comment: He's using frameworks which generate the SQL, they want something that will catch the sql being generated.

Comment: Yes I'm already using log4net, the question is how to hook it into the ado.net pipeline